# Words Checker in Android App

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I would like to make an android word game, which needs a WordsChecker.
The similar apps which is using the checker are: Word With Friends, Scramble With Friends, ... You can go to Google Play, download & install the app, then try to use it.

Currently I have no clue to write the WordsChecker similar to these apps, I have researched a bit but some solutions are not fine to me.

Anyone have any ideas? Can you help me?

Comment: what experience do you have with programming? And what specifically do you mean by "Words Checker"

Comment: "Word Checker" means the Checker which can check the word valid or invalid in English. As I mentioned, you can simply download the similar apps in Google Play as I listed to see how it works.

Comment: I am familiar with the games. There are different ways to achieve it. My guess would be that they use an SQLite database that contains all of the words that count as valid and run queries on it to check if a word being played is valid.

Comment: Thank you Tim. My another question is how about the plural cases, and tense cases in English? I don't think they put both plural cases and tense cases into database, because if they do that, they will make the database more bigger and it is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a trie data structure (google it), then the words can be found efficiently and the cost of storing plurals and other tenses is negligible.

A trie is a tree structure that starts at a root node.  Every child is indexed by a letter so every node corresponds to the words up to this point.  A flag in each node indicates whether or not this is a complete word.

To find a word like "cars", start at the root, cross the C link to a node, then cross the A link to the next node then the R link to the next node.  At this point, the node is marked as a complete word (CAR) but you can still cross the S link to the node representing CARS which is also marked as a complete word.

Comment: Your explanation about trie data structure make me think it is good. :) I will try to google it a bit. If you can have a sample, please give me also.

Comment: My another question: I got the idea about trie data structure, but the words should be stored in database or a file, right? So loading all words into the trie is not good. Any idea?

Comment: Let's assume that your database file will be a maximum of 16Mb in size and that you'll be searching for English words only.

Comment: If you represent the "end of word" as a transition, you only need to store transitions in the file, not nodes.  Each transition could be 4 consecutive bytes in the file.  The first byte is the letter for the transition (0 means an end of word is possible, 255 means there are no more possible letters to search). If the first byte matches the next letter in the word, use the remaining 3 bytes as the offset in the file to start searching for the next letter. If the first byte doesn't match, read 4 more bytes and try matching the letter again.

Comment: As an optimization if you need it, cache the first two levels of the trie into RAM and access them from there.  It will be faster getting through those first two levels than trying to ready from a file all the time.

Comment: Actually I don't understand fully your idea. But I know that Trie is the best solution for my case. Thank you. I just need that, I will do by myself more to solve my problem. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm also wondering who did downvote my question :) Maybe they can't solve or give me the good solutions like you, then they did votedown :)) haha

Comment: Anything :) The main is I FOUND THE SOLUTION. :)

Comment: The dictionary I linked is under 700KB, not 16MB! 
Also weird: someone came through and voted ALL the answers down one, including Simberon's. Oh well, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I couldn't find a class that did this, but what you can do is call a website such as dictionary.com with the word as part of the parameters. Scrape the html and check if the word actually exists.

Comment: The checking should be done fastly and correctly, then it should do internally itself instead of basing on the website, then the game will be very slow. BTW, thank you for suggesting dictionary.com.

Comment: I agree, the best solution would be to find a database and related class that would wrap this. With some googling it is probably out there somewhere.

Comment: Yep. I'm still trying to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this dictionary on the java site. I don't know how "good" it is, for example, comparing it to the "Official Scrabble" word list.

Trie data structure might be overkill. I haven't tried it, myself yet. (Pun seems to be unavoidable, so sorry.) You might consider converting the words to a numeric form (the hashCodes for strings might be just fine, though) and storing them in a hashset. I say hash SET because all you really need to know is membership. The quickest way I know of to test if a member of a list exists is to try to add it to a HashSet: if it fails, it is already a member. If it succeeds, then it is not a word and don't forget to remove it!

I was using this programming strategy while playing around with aspects of Boggle, and used it to make lists of word frequencies, given the specific Boggle cubes.

If there is a structure that pertains to your search, e.g., you know you are going to be searching in a certain order, not random access, then a more structured approach like a trie makes good sense for optimization. But consider also, a turn-based word game hardly requires blazing performance! (KISS)

What grouchiness to vote the question down! I found it difficult to get traction on this problem when I was first getting into this subject, so I have some sympathy for the original poster. I'm giving the question +1 to counterbalance this.